# Включение терминала CentOS 7

Tags: linux, консоль, centos, виртуальная-машина

Установил виртуальную машину https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php . Как включить терминал из gnome интерфейса (он мне что-то перестает нравиться)?

Answer (score 0):

Приложение может называться Konsole, Terminal, Xterm или UXterm. Есть ли у вас что-то из этого?